# Can I install this driver?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, ati, graphics

I have an ATI Xpress 200 graphics card, it doesn't have support from AMD anymore so I can't upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10, but I found this driver on their site [Driver Download](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx).
I know it doesn't support my graphics card but should I take the risk and install so I can upgrade to 12.10?

update: I have an issue with the reboot which finishes the upgrade. I press the reboot button and then my pc reboots: I see the bios, then my sreen turns purple and then black and my monitor says that it gets no signal and the hard drive led light stops flashing

Comment: You can try [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal.html) as mentioned in the answer of [What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx)?](http://askubuntu.com/a/129200)

Comment: but now i'm pretty sure that i have a opensource driver installed

Comment: If everything works, why do you ask?

Answer (score 1):

With this card, use the open source radeon drivers, no installation is necessary, it is in the kernel.

Comment: don't you have to select what drivers to be used?

Comment: If you are using the open source drivers, then no.

Comment: see my update (ps thx for the help already)